# Can any isometry between two non-empty subsets of $\mathbb R$ be extended to an isometry of $\mathbb R$ onto itself?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, isometry

Let $A , B$ be  non-empty subsets of $\mathbb R$ and $f:A \to B$ be a function such that $|f(a)-f(b)|=|a-b| , \forall a,b \in A$ , then is it true that there exists a function $g :\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ such that $|g(x)-g(y)|=|x-y|,\forall x,y \in \mathbb R$ and $g_{|A}=f$ ? If the answer is yes , then can we make $g$  to be surjective also ?

Comment: What has thy research shown?

Comment: @ZelosMalum : I feel it can be done ( intuitively only ) :p

Comment: Does the functions need to be continuous?

Comment: @ZelosMalum : any isometry is trivially continuous :)

Comment: Making sure as the question said function while the title said isometry

Comment: @ZelosMalum Shouldn't that be "hath"?

Comment: it should :O it should indeed

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Show that once you define $f$ on two points, it is uniquely determined on all other points.  As an example, if $f(0)=1$ and $f(1)=2$, can you prove that $f(x)=x+1$ for all $x\in A$?

Comment: if $f$ is an isometry on $\mathbb R$ then so is $f-f(0)$ which fixes the origin , hence $f(x)-f(0)$ must be an inner-product preserving linear map , and since for $\mathbb R$ , the usual inner product is just the multiplication , so the only inner-product preserving linear maps are $T(x)=x ; T(x)=-x$ , hence if $f$ is an isometry on real line , then $f(x)=f(0)+x$ or $f(x)=f(0)-x$ . But an isometry on $A$ (which is not a linear space) need not necessarily be like this ... so could you please elaborate on your hint ?

Comment: Try just using the definition of isometry directly, using the two points you have already and the unknown value of $f$ at any third point.